# Keep checkbox status for multiple checkboxes with same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a page of content generated by ajax and organized with a row of checkboxes. Clicking on any of the checkboxes passes a parameter into the URL and that's used to create a SQL query. I want to add the checkboxes to another section of the page but when I do this, I'm unable to keep the checkboxes styled (there's a custom style for a checked and unchecked state). Click on either row of checkboxes will organize the data properly, but only one row of checkboxes will show the checked-on/checked-off state.

I'm using the following code to style the checkboxes:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).next('label').children('div').removeClass("sort-not-active").addClass("sort-active");
    }
    else {
        $(this).next('label').children('div').removeClass("sort-active").addClass("sort-not-active");
    }
});
```

The HTML for my checkboxes is below. I figured my style issues might be caused because I'm passing the variable as an ID instead of a class, but whenever I remove the ID the checkboxes stop working altogether.

```
<?php foreach (array_unique($disciplines) as $discipline): ?>
    <input class="disciplinechecks" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $discipline; ?>" name="<?php echo $discipline; ?>" value="<?php echo $discipline; ?>" onChange="checkBoxChange(this.checked,'<?php echo $discipline; ?>');">
    <label for="<?php echo $discipline; ?>">
        <div class="sort-genre sort-active"><?php echo $discipline; ?></div>
        <span></span>
    </label>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Below is the function I use to pass the values into the URL. Nothing here references an ID so I can't figure out why removing the ID from my checkboxes breaks it:

```
var typeItemsChecked = Array( ALL OF THE $DISCIPLINE VALUES ARE HERE );

function checkBoxChange(x,y) {
    if(x){
        var type = y;
        typeItemsChecked.push(type);
        showUser();
    }
    else {
        var type = y;
        typeItemsChecked.remove(type);
        showUser();
    }
}

function getURLString() {
    joinedTypeItemsChecked = typeItemsChecked.join();
    var queryString = [
        ("d="+joinedTypeItemsChecked)
    ];

    var url = queryString.join("&");
    return url;
}
```

This is what the HTML looks like after the PHP

```
<input class="disciplinechecks" type="checkbox" id="Web Design" name="Web Design" value="Web Design" onChange="checkBoxChange(this.checked,'Web Design');">
<label for="Web Design">
    <div class="sort-genre sort-active">Web Design</div>
    <span></span>
</label>

<input class="disciplinechecks" type="checkbox" id="Print Design" name="Print Design" value="Print Design" onChange="checkBoxChange(this.checked,'Print Design');">
<label for="Print Design">
    <div class="sort-genre sort-active">Print Design</div>
    <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of some final HTML (e.g., after the PHP has been processed)?

Comment: Sure I added it in above

Comment: So, in a second line of checkboxes (the one that isn't working), would they use those same attribute values for the `id`, `name`, etc. or would it be based on a different set of `$discipline` values?

Comment: It is completely identical

Comment: Are both sets of checkboxes on the page when it loads or is the second one added later?

Comment: Both boxes are always on the page, however the second box is only visible when the user scrolls down the page. It is set to display none until activated by the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, after reading your comment responses, nothing in your original post jumps out at me immediately as an issue, but there are a couple of problems that your "processed" code has (particularly around the `id` and `name` attributes) that could be causing you troubles.  Specifically:

1. `id` attributes can not contain spaces (see here for more information on valid `id` values: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html))
2. `id` values must be unique within the page
3. Multiple checkboxes (and, on a side note, radio buttons) that have the same `name` attribute, are considered to be grouped (i.e., sort of like they are one input).

Now, browsers can often be pretty forgiving about these things, but scripting languages can get very confused.  So, before you go any further in your debugging, I would suggest updating your PHP to:

- strip any spaces out of the `$discipline` value, when assigning the `id` attribute.  While `name` attributes can have spaces, I would avoid using them there as well, as a general practice.
- use some sort of index value (or something similar) to differentiate the `id` and `name` values between the two sets of checkboxes.

---

### On a side note . . .

. . . there are also a couple of places where you can simplify your code . . . doing that will also reduce the number of places where bugs can pop up.  Specifically:

In you JS code for the styling, try this:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).next().children('div').toggleClass("sort-not-active sort-active");
});
```

- no need to specify `'label'` in the `next()` call, since it is always the next sibling of the checkbox
- if the default classes are set up correctly, then all you need to do is toggle the two classes on the change of the checkbox.  Since there are only two states that the checkbox can be in, there are only two states that the combination of classes can be in.

For the code for capturing the checked boxes, you can simplify it to this:

```
function checkBoxChange(x,y) {
    if (x) {
        typeItemsChecked.push(y);
    }
    else {
        typeItemsChecked.remove(y);
    }
    showUser();
}
```

I don't see any reason that this would be causing the problems that you are seeing, but I just thought that I would toss that out to help reduce the complexity a little bit.   :)

---

So, I'm not guaranteeing that any of these are going to fix the issue that you are seeing (actually, using just your original JS for the styles and the HTML samples that you gave, everything worked just fine for me in Firefox), but I do know that some browsers and scripting languages can be very particular about not following the correct rules of HTML.  Try addressing some of these issues and see if the problems that you are seeing go away.  If not, we can try again with your new code.

Comment: The reason I have spaces in the id is because the checkboxes don't work if the id value is different from the actual value. As a test, I removed the second set of checkboxes altogether and removed with the spaces in the id with a simple str_replace. When I do that checkboxes working.

Comment: Ok I still don't understand why my script is pulling data from the ID instead of the value attribute, but I managed to solve the style issue by updating the checkbox change function to include a variable (the ID of the checkbox), and toggling the style against $('input:checkbox[id="'+theID+'"]') instead of $(this)